# How to combine these two queries and have them be as fast?

Tags: mysql

I have a very legacy system with millions upon millions of records. It is very poorly managed and maintained, originally having been an Access database.

So in one particular look-up I am getting the asset deployment history for a particular employee. Their name is searched in the employee table to find their Employee ID. Their employee ID is then searched in the PC history table.

Right now I have two queries that are fast:

```
SELECT `tbl_employee`.EMPLID 
FROM `tbl_employee` 
WHERE `tbl_employee`.NAME 
LIKE "%Smith,John%"
```

The above query takes 0.0250 to 0.0850 seconds to resolve in benchmarks. In this case the employee ID is `518266`.

I can re-use this result in the next query:

```
SELECT `tbl_pc history`.SerialNumber, `tbl_pc history`.Date, `tbl_pc history`.ModelID 
FROM `tbl_pc history` 
WHERE `tbl_pc history`.`EmployeeNumber` 
LIKE "%518266%";
```

This is also very fast, between 0.0340 and 0.0679 seconds in benchmarks.

I now arrive at what I want, a list of 4 items from millions which were at some point issued to this employee.

I have tried to combine this query a couple of ways and they resulted in several second resolution times, instead of fractions of a second:

```
SELECT `tbl_pc history`.SerialNumber, `tbl_pc history`.Date, `tbl_pc history`.ModelID 
FROM `tbl_pc history` 
WHERE `tbl_pc history`.`EmployeeNumber` 
IN 
    (SELECT tbl_employee.EMPLID 
    FROM tbl_employee 
    WHERE tbl_employee.NAME 
    LIKE "%Smith,John%");
```

The above query gets me what I want, but takes 4.8508 to 6.3010 seconds to execute.

```
SELECT `tbl_pc history`.`SerialNumber`, `tbl_pc history`.`Date`, tbl_employee.NAME, `tbl_pc history`.`ModelID` 
FROM `tbl_employee` 
INNER JOIN `tbl_pc history` 
ON `tbl_pc history`.`EmployeeNumber` = tbl_employee.EMPLID 
WHERE `tbl_employee`.`NAME` 
LIKE "%Smith,John%"
```

This also results in 4-6 second queries.

Please excuse my ignorance in this area - I have next to no knowledge of databases, SQL, PHP, or any of this and have been blindly googling my way to solutions for the past couple of weeks.

Comment: Please tag your MySql version, and add the table schema plus index.

Answer (score 0):

Would help if you post `SHOW CREATE TABLE` for the two tables and also how many rows each table has.

Most likely the slowness is due to use of `LIKE "%Smith,John%"`. This will do a full table scan on `tbl_employee`.

Try `LIKE "Smith,John%"` just to see if the query performance is any better this way. I am assuming you have an index on `tbl_employee.name` column.

Answer (score 0):

Few recommendations:

1. Avoid leading wildcard in LIKE searches if you can. Will it be enough to search for LIKE `"%Smith,John%"` instead of LIKE `"%Smith,John%"`? If not, consider full text indexing.
2. Make sure you have the relevant indexes in place:

   ALTER TABLE `tbl_employee` ADD INDEX `tbl_employee_index_1` (`EMPLID`, `NAME`);
   ALTER TABLE `tbl_pc history` ADD INDEX `tbl_pc history_index_1` (`EmployeeNumber`, `SerialNumber`, `Date`, `ModelID`);